# Getting 9002 error while connecting to Access Remedy Server via Java AR API

Tags: java, remedy

I am trying to connect to Access Remedy Server for creating ticket in BMC Remedy via Java but it is giving error i.e.

> ERROR (9002): The data encryption key exchange failed;

Access Remedy Application host that I am  trying to connect is encrypted and we have added cryptojce.jar,cryptocommon.jar, and jcmFIPS.jar

I can see one argument getting passed mentioned below.

```
com.bmc.arsys.arencrypt.c:? - fipsProviderJsafeJCE installed = false
```

Is there anything I am missing here to enable proper exchange of encryption key?

I am using Java 8 on tomcat v9. and using arapi7604_build002-1.0-arapi7604_build002.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution, we need to upgrade our Arapi jar to Arapi9 in order to support premium encryption.